# Positioning nested divs with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position child divs within parent divs, however the child divs are overflowing outside parent divs. Please run the code below in a browser, to have a better idea of the problem:

I want to position the inner most divs horizotally and the outer divs shoud just fit the inner div.

```
 <div class='list' id='list1' style='padding: 1px; border : 5px groove; position: absolute; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; ' >
    <div class='tuple tuple1' id='tuple1_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; position: relative; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
        <div class='elmnt elmnt1 elmnt1_1' id='elmnt1_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: relative; left: 6px;  min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
            <div class='list' id='list2' style='padding: 1px; border : 5px groove; position: absolute; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto; ' >
                <div class='tuple tuple2' id='tuple2_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px solid; position: relative; min-width: 3px; width: auto; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_1' id='elmnt2_1' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: relative; left: 6px;  min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >jdk-7u11-linux-i586.rpm</div>
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_2' id='elmnt2_2' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 112px; top: 2px; min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >107M </div>
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_3' id='elmnt2_3' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 218px; top: 2px; min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >nadeem </div>
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_4' id='elmnt2_4' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 2px; min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >2013-01-23 </div>
                    <div class='elmnt elmnt2 elmnt2_5' id='elmnt2_5' style='padding: 2px; border : 1px dotted; position: absolute; left: 430px; top: 2px; min-width: 3px; width: 100; min-height: 3px; height: auto;' >00:53 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code in http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/

Comment: If you position an element on your page with position absolute, the element is removed from the so called document flow and other elements don't care for them anymore. Also you should clarify what exactly you want to achieve there.

Comment: This URL contains the information referenced above by kleinfreund.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position  It does not specifically say you have to set the width of the box, but because it has been taken out of the document flow and you have nested items with different positioning schemas, I would imagine you would need to set the width programmatically to fit the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `position` property to `absolute` causes your `div`s to collapse. Remove or change the property and the `div`s will wrap around the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/1/

Comment: Thanks, to position the inner divs horizontally i have further added float: left to the divs. However, the height of the parent div collapses: http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/2/

Comment: Set `overflow: hidden` on the container (#tuple2_1 in this case) of the floated elements, this will force the container to wrap the elements. http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/3/

Comment: how can I make the width of the parent div to just wrap around the children too?

Comment: Unless you've specified a width, there shouldn't be an issue with it wrapping horizontally. If you have, adjust the width accordingly.

Comment: the width is not known beforehand and varies according to the width of the child divs. I am not sure why the width : auto attribute wraps it horizontally. Ofcourse I can us js to calculate the width, but is there a way using css to wrap it horizontally and change automatically as width of child divs change?

Comment: As you've mentioned 'width: auto' will cause the width to be calculated according to the content's width. Doesn't that serve your purpose?

Comment: I missed a NOT in the previous comment, width : auto does not wrap the parent div to the content's div, as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/YMsR4/3/

Comment: @user1628340 `div`s are treated as `block` elements, which implies that they will take up the entire width of the container. To make them collapse to the width of their content, either set the `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block`, OR set the `float` property

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to scroll you would need to add an overflow attribute to the div that is to serve as the parent.

For example adding

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the #list2 causes all of the children to scroll within it.

Comment: do not want to scroll them, jsut want to position the inner most divs horizotally and the outer divs shoud just fit the inner div.

Comment: Once you absolutely position an object I believe you have to manually set the width.  Something else to consider is how you are setting the width attribute.  You should be including the measurement on the value for example width: 100px instead of width:100.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with what others have suggested. Using absolute positioning is what is making the flow different than your expectations. I would try making the DIVs position:relative and float:left the child DIVs. In fact, assuming what you are trying to build here is a horizontal menu, I would use an unordered list to provide the structure instead of nested DIVs; something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 1</li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 2</li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 3</li>
  <li style="float:left;width:20%;color:white;background-color:#333;padding:4px 12px;">item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hyperlinks, and even images, can be added to make it functional. Once it displays as you prefer, you can move the inline CSS to a separate stylesheet for ease of maintenance.

NOTE: if you choose to use the float property, the element and its parent must be position:relative and a width should be specified.